# Creating a repeated sequence of zero and ones with uneven "breaks" between

Tags: r

I am trying to create a sequence consisting of 1 and 0 using Rstudio.
My desired output is a sequence that first has five 1 then six 0, followed by four 1 then six 0. Then this should all be repeat until the end of a given vector.

The result should be like this:

1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 .....

Hope someone has a good solution, and sorry if I have some grammar mistakes

Best,
HB

Answer (score 1):

```
rep(c(rep(1,5),rep(0,6),rep(1,4),rep(0,6)),n)
```

repeating your pattern n times.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!

Say that I want to repeat this sequence in a column in a dataframe, what should I replace the "n" with?

Comment: @HB96 Will the pattern fit nicely in your dataframe? Or will it have some excess?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It will have some excess, all depending on the length.

Think I found a solution though, by using function rep_len and length(dataframe$column) instead of n.

Like this:
rep_len(c(rep(1,5),rep(0,6),rep(1,4),rep(0,6)), length(dataframe$column))

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Map`.

```
unlist(Map(function(x, ...) c(rep(x, ...), rep(0, 6)), 1, times=length(v):1))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Instead of `length(v):1` you may also use `rev(seq(v))` but it's slower.

---

*Data*

```
v <- c("Vector", "of", "specific", "length", "five")
```